# How can I do this? It's very confusing for me to use abstraction

Tags: python

this is the code.

## Parent Class

```py
class MyPet:

    dogs = []

    def __init__(self, dogs):
        self.dogs = dogs
```

## Parent class

```py
class MyDog:

    species = 'mammal'     # Class Attribute
    
    def __init__(self, name, age):     # Initializer / Instance attributes
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def description(self):     # Instance Method 1
        return self.name, self.age

    def speak(self, sound):     # Instance Method 2
        return "%s says %s" % (self.name, sound)

    def eat(self):     # Instance Method 3
        self.is_hungry = False
```

## Child class (inherits from Dog class)

```py
class Bulldog(MyDog):
    def run(self, speed):
        return "%s runs %s" % (self.name, speed)
```

## Child class (inherits from Dog class)

```py
class RussellTerrier(MyDog):
    def run(self, speed):
        return "%s runs %s" % (self.name, speed)
```

## Child class (inherits from Dog class)

```py
class SiberianHusky(MyDog):
    def run(self, speed):
        return "%s runs %s" % (self.name, speed)
```

The output should be like this:

```
 These are my 3 dogs namely:

  Justin runs at the speed of 5.
  Drake runs at the speed of 6.
  Kanye runs at the speed of 7.
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to not override run. The parent class implementation can access ‘name my and ‘speed’ of the instances. See the already written “speak” method.

Comment: Why is each breed a subclass?

Comment: What is your question? Your title says 'How can I do this?', but you don't provide a specific question along with your code. Also, why are you creating three child classes that do the exact same method? You can just add that one method to the parent class instead. Also, if you were to do inheritance, you have to initialize the child class with the parent class's init. You would do this by `super().__init__(name, age)` under the init function.

Comment: Are Justin, Drake and Kanye objects of BullDog, RussellTerrier and SiberianHusky respectively? I'm not quite sure about what's your question, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `MyDog` does not inherit from `MyPet`? or vice versa? Is there supposed to be any relation between them?

Comment: *"How can I do this?"* is not a clear question, you have to state an actual question. **Do you want to use your 3 subclasses to instantiate 3 objects, 1 of each type of dog, each with the given `speed`, then call their `run()` methods to get the output in the desired form after "These are my 3 dogs..."?**

Answer (score 1):

We have 2 parent classes `MyDog` and `MyPet`.

Let's focus on `MyDog`

The code given is:

```
class MyDog: 
   species = 'mammal'     # Class Attribute

   def __init__(self, name, age):     # Initializer / Instance attributes
       self.name = name
       self.age = age

   def description(self):     # Instance Method 1
       return self.name, self.age

   def speak(self, sound):     # Instance Method 2
       return "%s says %s" % (self.name, sound)

   def eat(self):     # Instance Method 3
       self.is_hungry = False
```

Now let's take one sub-class (BullDog)

```
class BullDog(MyDog): 
    def run(self, speed):
        return "%s runs %s" % (self.name, speed)
```

If we initialize a new `BullDog` (i.e.

```
bd = BullDog(name, age)
```

Now `bd` has all the properties of `MyDog` as well as `run`. So we can say `bd.eat(); bd.speak("bark");`  so on and so forth.

If you want to learn more about inheritance feel free to ask in the comments/read this doc: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php